# map of pointers OR map of stack objects

Tags: c++, stl

I am stuck for choice between map_of_pointers OR map_of_stack_objects ( OR even map of shared_ptrs. )
Main operations on map would be insert/delete/search items.

Can anyone please help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

In response to your questions:-

```
Class Cache
{
private:   
 A map with key as int and value as AccountDetails
public:
 createitem
 deleteItem
 updateItem
 searchItem
};

class AccountDetails
{
AccountData a;  ( 20 bytes )
personalData b;  ( 20 bytes )
list < positions > c ( Each position is 20 bytes )
}
```

I believe I have explained enough to answer this question..If still I'm lacking something please let me know I will add it.

Comment: Impossible to answer without substantially more information, you've not even told us what these objects are

Comment: What are you going to use the map for? What's your use-cases? That will be the decider for you.

Comment: @ravi089: just use a `map<int, AccountDetails>` to start with - it's almost impossible to write it so badly it will crash - always good for beginners - then switch to smart pointers (or learn about move semantics) later if you find performance is bad because there are needless temporaries as you copy the `AccountDetails` objects in and out of the `map`.

Comment: Thanks TonyD. It seems I need to use map of boost::shared_ptrs for this ... Am I right? OR Are there any more concerns you take care of while using map of shared_ptr

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shoot-from-the-hip answer, hope it helps.

Using some kind of shared pointers means you have less probability of memory leaks when destroying the map. What do you mean with map of stack objects? Do you want to have the map contain pointers (naked or smart) to stuff on the stack? Not a good idea. 
When adding a new key,value to the map, the pair is stored on the heap (a std::map is implemented as a red-black tree), so the pair will not be on the stack.

Comment: By "map of stack objects" I mean your are just storing plain objects in map

Comment: @ravi089: which shows a fundamental misundertanding... the actual `map` object may or may not be on the stack, but it always allocates memory for the elements it contains dynamically... they're never on the stack, even if they were inserted by copying values that were on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would want to place the objects on the stack. That is, "map of stack objects" should do (by that, I assume you mean "not map of pointers" - because most probably, every element in the map will be allocated dynamically anyway).

You should keep a map of pointers only when:

- you only have access to pointers in code using the map, and you do not own them (i.e. you received the pointers from somewhere and need to store them)
- you need polymorphic behavior (i.e. you are storing pointers to a base class)

In the first case, you should store pointers. In the second, you should store smart pointers (and have the smart pointers in the map manage the lifetime of the objects).

Comment: I faced a problem using smart_pointers in my project. As map storing smart_pointers was also responsible for sending these objects to some other modules which in-turn would store them in vectors (let say). In this way objects which I deleted were never actually deleted from memory as there ref count never reached to zero.

Comment: agree with your second point ... but in that case also u should take care of completely owning those objects.